# Add Regular Expressions with grep

Tags: grep

I have to use grep to find 8 postcodes out of a text file, the order of characters of each postcode is as follows:
1. Capital letter
2. Digit
3. Capital letter
4. Space (optional)
5. Digit
6. Capital Letter
7. Digit

I have used the grep command:

```
grep '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9+[][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'
```

This has given me 5 postcodes which have a space at character 4

I have also used this grep command:

```
grep '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9\.][A-Z][0-9]'
```

This has given me the last 3 postcodes with no space at character 4.

I don't know how to write a command that states that a space can be optional. Thanks

Comment: Try `grep -E '...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ERE quantifier `?` means zero or one occurrences. So

```
grep -E '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]'
```

If you want to allow for zero *or more* spaces, change `?` to `*`. To allow tabs as well as spaces, you can use `[ \t]?`, `[[:blank:]]?`, or (in GNU grep) `\s?`

Comment: You can also use `\d` to match digit characters instead of `[0-9]` for the expression to be a bit smaller and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like below should work:

```
grep '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][ ]*[0-9][A-Z][0-9]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

```
grep -P "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][ ]{0,1}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]" file
```